# Handle specific Exceptions in php

Tags: php, exception

I want to catch a specific Exception and handle it properly. However, I have not done this before and I want to do it in the best way.

Will it be correct to create a separate class something like

```
 class HandleException extends Exception
{
   //my code to handle exceptions;
}
```

and in it have different methods handling the different exception cases? As far as I understand, the Exception class is like an "integrated" class in php so it can be extended and if an Exception is caught it is not obligatory to terminate the flow of the program?

And, an instance of this class will be created when an exception is caught? Sth. like

```
     catch ( \Exception $e ) {
        $error = new HandleException;
    }
```

Comment: No, this isn't right. Please read https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php and then (once you fully understand how built-in exceptions work) https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php

Comment: To handle specific kind of exceptions, you have to cerate your own exceptions (that's right) but in your business logic you have to throw the exception you created and then catch it (wherever you want to do the handling logic.) check this example here : https://eval.in/627662

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **CAN** extend the basic Exception object with your own, to provide your own exception types, e.g.

```
class FooExcept extends Exception { .... }
class BarExcept extends Exception { .... }

try {
   if ($something) {
      throw new FooExcept('Foo happened');
   } else if ($somethingelse) {
      throw new BarExcept('Bar happened');
   }
} catch (FooExcept $e) {
    .. foo happened, fix it...
} catch (BarExcept $e) {
    ... bar happened, fix it ...
}
```

If an Exception is caught, then the program DOESN'T necessarily have to abort. That'd be up to the exception handler itself. But if an exception bubbles always back up to the top of the call stack and ISN'T caught, then the entire script will abort with an unhandled exception error.

Answer (score 5):

From the manual

> Multiple catch blocks can be used to catch different classes of
>   exceptions. Normal execution (when no exception is thrown within the
>   try block) will continue after that last catch block defined in
>   sequence. Exceptions can be thrown (or re-thrown) within a catch
>   block.

So you can do something like this:

```
try {
    // some code
} catch ( HandleException $e ) {
    // handle sthis error
} catch ( \Exception $e ) {
    // handle that error
}
```

This will handle different exceptions. You can also use the `finally` keyword with newer versions of PHP.